# OR Operation in if operation

Tags: c, if-statement

I'm new in Native C Language but I didnt see an error.

Im trying to use a if operation in that Case:

```
#define PAGE_A 0 
#define PAGE_B 1

int pageID = 0;


if (pageID != PAGE_A || pageID != PAGE_B) {

    //Do something
}
```

But it dont work. If page ID = 0 or 1 it goes to "do something". If I just write:

```
if (pageID != PAGE_A) {

    //Do something
}
```

It works. If pageID = 1-x its goes to "do something" otherwise it dont...

Comment: `pageID != PAGE_A || pageID != PAGE_B` is always true, I suggest `&&`.

Answer (score 0):

The logical OR operator `||` evaluates to true if *either* operand is true.

If `pageID` is 0, the first condition is false but the second is true so the whole expression evaluates to true.  Similarly, if `pageID` is 1, the first condition is true but the second is false so the whole expression evaluates to true.  If `pageID` is any other value, but conditions are true so the whole expression is true.

What you want instead is the logical AND operator `&&`, which is only true if *both* operands evaluate to true.

```
if (pageID != PAGE_A && pageID != PAGE_B) {
```

Reading this out, the condition will be true if both `pageID` is not 0 and `pageID` is not 1.